# no module name 'mysql'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have intalled mysql plugins and lib in python using pip and it is working when I am using it in pycharm. But if I try to execute the same using cmd prompt using command python and the file name it throws an error saying **"no module name 'mysql'"**. So I also checked it in the libs of python34 directory and I can see the package available over there. I am not able to figure out what is the problem and how to overcome that. 
And this is my code which is working fine in pycharm but throws error if I try to execute it with cmd prompt

---

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

class DBConnection:
    global connect
    global config

    def __init__(self):
        "Setting the paramenter to set the DB"
        config = {
            'user': 'root',
            'password': 'VMware@1234',
            'host': '127.0.0.1',
            'database': 'super_nova',
            'raise_on_warnings': True,
        };

    def connectToDB(self):
        "connection of the database is done here"
        try:
            #connect = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
            connect = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='VMware@1234',host='127.0.0.1' ,database='super_nova')
            return connect
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                print("Database does not exist")
            else:
                print(err)


    def closeDB(self,connection):
        "Make sures the connections is closed"
        connection.close()
```

---

```
from com.test import test2

def fun():
    test2.DBConnection().connectToDB()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun()
```

---

And the error message is :

> > ```
> > from com.test import test2   File "C:\Users\nkumarn\TestPythons\com\test\test2.py", line 1, in <module>
> > import mysql.connector ImportError: No module named 'mysql'
> > ```

please help me to sort it out.
thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: Are you sure you use the same python in command prompt?

Comment: yes I am working with the same python... I checked with my environment variable as well, its python 3.4

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv ?

Comment: NB : totally unrelated, but using a class to declare and mutate globals is a total WTF. One of the points of OO is to avoid globals as much as possible.

Comment: Maybe module name is not mysql? Have a look in the site-packages folder to check the name. you can see the site-packages folder in sys.path.